# My tensorflow defaults to using my GPU instead of CPU, which is like 10 times slower. How do I fix this and make it use the CPU?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

I have one of those gaming laptops with a discrete GPU and dedicated GPU (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070).

I was getting very slow speeds training neural networks on tensorflow. Many, many times slower than another laptop with vastly inferior specs in CPU and GPU.

I think the reason for this slowness is because tensorflow is probably running on the dedicate GPU because when I disable the dedicated GPU, the training time speeds up, like 10 times faster. These are huge differences, an order of magnitude.

I know the kernel is running on the dedicated GPU by default because when I disable the dedicated GPU in the middle of the session, the kernel dies.

Therefore, I think disabling the dedicated GPU has forced it to run on the CPU (AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX), which should be better.

I'm running this on Anaconda using Jupyter Notebook.

How do I force it to use by CPU instead of my GPU.

Edit: This seems to be a complicated issue. Some more information.

- With dedicated GPU disabled, when training, according to the task manager the GPU usage is 0% (as expected) and the CPU usage is 40%.
- But with dedicated GPU enabled, when training, GPU usage is about 10% and CPU usage is about 20%. This is 10 times slower than the above. Why is it using both, but less CPU?
- With dedicated GPU enabled (i.e. the normal situation), according to the task manager, scikit-learn uses the CPU not the GPU. So this problem is specific to tensorflow.
- Killing the dedicated GPU in the middle of the session crashes not only the kernel, but opening Jupyter Notebooks as well.
- Forcing Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook to use the integrated GPU instead of the dedicated GPU in the Windows Setting doesn't fix the problem. It's still using the dedicated GPU.

Comment: How did you install tensorflow?

Comment: @AnhPC03 I installed tensorflow using Anaconda. Using command line like this https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow. I didn't change any settings or anything like that.

Comment: Could you show me `pip3 list | grep tensorflow`?

Comment: @AnhPC03 where do I type that? I put into the the CMD in Anaconda and it says: 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: you used windows in stead of linux, so let me see the output when you type in cmd: `pip3 list | findstr tensorflow`

Comment: @AnhPC03 It says: tensorflow                         2.6.0
tensorflow-estimator               2.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Just tell tensorflow to do so:

```
with tf.device("/CPU:0"): #name might vary
   model.fit(...)
```

Comment: Tried that with 0, 1, 2. Doesn't work. It's still 10 times slower than it should be.

Comment: @fe2084 you can check what devices you have available using `tf.config.list_physical_devices`.. how fast they are is not related with the code you use to tell him which to use... (and usually GPU are faster than CPU, so I would not expect an improvement in speed using CPU as you want)

Comment: According to tf.config.list_physical_devices('CPU') and tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') there's 1 CPU and 1 GPU. I've tried every combination, it's very slow, and disabling the dedicated GPU makes it run 10 times faster.

Comment: @fe2084 then with device(cpu) you should be good to go, wasn’t this your question?